# Expected behavior of peer in case of all orderers down

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, peer

In Hyperledger Fabric, what is the expected behavior of peer when all orderer nodes are down.
Should peer also down, or stop serving request from client, or continue to serve query request?

In our test, after orderers are stopped, the peer keeps writing "failed to create connection to orderer"  log. When we query a key by calling chaincode the value is returned.

Can you help clarify if this is expected behavior. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a distributed hyperledger fabric network. I would recommend the Orderer Raft Consensus https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/orderer/ordering_service.html#ordering-service-implementations.
I have solved this in such a way that in my case I have three orderers that run independently on different environments.
If I crash all these orderers, the peer containers will continue to run on the other participants of the network. As you said, they cannot make any transactions.
If one of my orderers crashes it is not so bad after the raft consensus, the containers keep running. If another one fails, no transactions can be made. In this case I let the peers continue and check if the orderers are available again.

The behaviour you described I would put down to the fact that the peer requests the value from his ledger, he doesn't need an orderer for that. https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/master/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getState

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/source/peers/peers.md This is the best documentation for how the system works I've found and there's more in the docs directory on the repo for orderers, etc.

My understanding is: The peers are there to sign (endorse) transaction proposals. The orderer exists to order, validate, package and distribute transactions to peers. The peers can also distribute their knowledge of validated transactions via the gossip channel.

If all orderers go down, the transactions will not be validated/packaged/distributed so the blockchain will be out of action until the orderers are restored.

> When we query a key by calling chaincode the value is returned.

Peers will still remain up and ready to sign/endorse transaction proposals, and querying the blockchain held at the peers will still work. Chaincodes are hosted by the peers. Orderers do not host chaincode.

Also see here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/source/orderer/ordering_service.md#ordering-service-implementations for the various modes the orderer can be run in: Raft mode, Kafka ordering, Solo ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I think the current observerd behavour is expected and in my view it is just fine.

Let's check the purpose of orderer?

1. Order the transactions
2. Cut the block and distribute the block amongst the orgs when the criteria is met ( min txn/size or time).

This also means, orderer is needed when your Fabric network is processing those transactions which intend to write data into the ledger, isnt it? And Query is not a transaction which writes into the ledger. So it doesn't need the orderer. For query, it will pick up the data from the peer's local database.

So I think what could be done is, to send out an alert to the production support when your application detect orderer node down ( with some health check ? ). And your application displays a *dimnished capacity/limited operations* message while work on bringing up the orderer network, the system can still serve the search queries.

From my view, its just fantastic. But its finally upto you. Cheers!!